# useEffect hook is not waiting for an async depency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using useEffect hook to implement some logic after an async function that contains an API call return an array of objects which is the the dependecy of the hook.

**The problem** is that the hook itself is not waiting for the array to change in order to execute the logic inside of it, it just executes even if `availableSites` is still `[]`:

```
const [availableSites, setAvailableSites] = useState([]);

useEffect(initialize, [getAxiosInstance])

async function initialize() {
    // ...
    const initPage = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await getAxiosInstance().get(GetObjects); // Api EndPoint
        if (response.data) {
          setAvailableSites(response.data); // data for availableSites
          const Secondresponse = await somePromise(); // Another API call thas lasts around 10 seconds
          if (response && response.status === 200) {
            // ...
          }
        }
      } catch {
        // ...
      }
    };
    initPage();
  }
        
// useEffect that is failing
useEffect(() => {
  // I want this to happen when availableSites has recieved the data
}, [availableSites]);
```

Answer (score 6):

`useEffect` is always going to execute at least once, doesn't matter what dependencies it has. If you only want it to execute when the data is set, use something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(availableSites.length > 0) {
    doSomething...
  }
}, [availableSites]);
```

If availableSites coming from the backend could be empty, set the initial state of availableSites to `null` and check if it's not `null` in the useEffect

Comment: Or you add it into the same `useEffect` function and await the previous execution of `initializeinitialize` before going into the other things needed

Answer (score 0):

If we have multiple instances of useEffect in the component, all the useEffect functions will be executed in the same order as they are defined inside the component the behavior you're getting is expected. Try checking if the array length has changed since the second useEffect depends on the [availableSites] so it will run again if the values of [availableSites] change.