# React useEffect hooks running async without waiting for data to fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React `18.2.0` and below is my file structure of `src` folder.

```
├── App.js
├── assets
│   └── logo
│       └── logo.png
├── index.js
└── views
    ├── Home
    │   ├── components
    │   │   ├── availstudents.js
    │   │   ├── cards.js
    │   │   ├── chart.js
    │   │   └── nav.js
    │   ├── HomeContext.js
    │   └── home.js
    ├── Login
    │   ├── login.css
    │   └── login.js
    └── NotFound
        └── 404.js
```

##### The idea of what my app does and what it shoud:

The idea of app is very simple. The app has a drop-down where it can see list of students of a class. On selecting a student from the dropdown (`students_list`), the history of that student is fetched from school API and plot the graph.

Currently I have hard-coded list of 3 students in the class with their ID. Below is how my `HomeContext.js` looks like which is the main point. Here is from where the list of students, their details are passed. We can say this is the starting point of the app.

```
const GlobalContext = createContext();
export function GlobalContextProvider({ children }) {
  const students_list = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "benjamin"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "hana"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "basil"
    }
];

  const [selectedstudent, setSelectedstudent] = students_list(options[0].name);
  const [memberhistory, setMemberhistory] = useState([]);
  const  FindStudentid = (selectedstudent) => options.find((x) => x.name===selectedstudent);
  const studid = FindStudentid(selectedstudent)

  const aboutschool = [
    { school: "xyz" },
    { rank: 33 },
    { strength: 1000 },
    { internet: "yes" }
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
      axios
      .get(`https://schoolapi.xyz/get_studenthistory/${studid.id}/`)
      .then(data => {
        console.log("<< hit API! >>");
        setMemberhistory(data.data)
    })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        setMemberhistory([],[])
      });
  }, [selectedstudent]);

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ students_list, aboutschool, setSelectedstudent, memberhistory }}>
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
}
export default GlobalContext;
```

Okay, now i will also give the 2nd last part of the app. Which is the `availstudents.js`.

```
import GlobalContext from "../HomeContext";
import { useContext } from "react";

function StudentDropdown() {
  const { students_list, setSelectedstudent } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedstudent(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        className="btn btn-default"
        defaultValue=""
        onChange={handleChange}>
        {students_list.map((option) => (
          <option key={option.name} value={option.name}>
            {option.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
export default StudentDropdown;
```

Now, this hopefully explained the fully story of what my simple app does.

- The list of students is passed from the `HomeContext.js` to `availstudents.js` and it creates a dropdown from that list.
- On selecting a student from this dropdown in `availstudents`, it simply sets the `selectedstudent` state.
- The useEffect in `HomeContext` is triggerd on changing the student dropdown.
- Hence the axios request is made and graph and few basic info is passed to child components.

Well, my app works very nicely so far. Now, i want to add one more simple thing to complete this app.
I want to get the list of students from the API rather than the hard-coded version we have. The API returns the studentlist exactly the same way as i have hard-coded.

For this, i have added a useEffect hook just like below to `HomeContext.js` before the hook to fetch student history.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios
      .get(`https://schoolapi.xyz/get_allstudents/`)
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.data)
        setSelectedstudent(avail_students[0].name) //setting 0th student for deafult view
    })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
 }, []);
```

This is what is added in the `HomeContext` before the history hook. I.e the student must be selected beforehand to fetch the history for that person because the axios request for `get_studenthistory` needs `studid.id` in the url param if you notice.

Here's the problem. In React if i know, useEffect hooks run in async manner. So the current issue is, both the useEffect will run parallel. One for getting student list and setting the 0th student as default and another one runs when we change studen from dropdown.

It is very clear that the first useEffect **should run** before running the 2nd useEffect for getting the histor for that student.

But in my case and in everyone's case i believe, both hooks run parallell and so it'll through error such as `TypeError undefined id in studid.id`. I have logged the code and i can see the 2nd useEffect doesnot wait for the 1st one to complete.

With this said, how can we solve this or how can we do this better? How can we avoid such situations in feature where there is one data which the entire app is dependend on. Here the whole app is dependednd in student_list and hence must  be provided first. I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67221246/6655469). Is this the way to solve this? by conditions whether `students_list` value exists, then proceed.

I hope this explained my problem very well and thanks for reading!

Tried putting the hook for fetching student_list in `home.js`

```
function Home(){
// useEffect hook for getting students_list
}
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalContextProvider>
        <Nav />
          <Cards />
        </div>
        <FuelHistChart />
      </GlobalContextProvider>
    </>
```

And it was passeed to `GlobalContextProvider` as props. For some reason, i did not get those props in `HomeContext.js`. Even if it could, do we have any assurance that students_list hook ran first before any other.

Comment: You'll need to handle a state where `selectedstudent` and/or `studid` are `undefined`. Just *don't* do the ajax request in the second `useEffect` in that case - it'll happen when the state is changed.

Comment: If i understand your idea correctly, i need to add condition in 2nd useEffectc saying if `studid` is not `undefined`, proceed with api call. Else? How do i wait/know when the first API call is complete? By checking the state of `selectedstudent` ? If so, when the value is set, will the 2nd hooks re-run? if yes, that's a solution. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: …`else` just do nothing. The effect will run again when the `selectedstudent` changes, that's what the dependency is for.

Comment: This also means, I've to write conditional to check whether `selectedstudent` is not null in all useEffect I'm going to write/written? I can't figure out well the `..else` just do nothing. From the code I sent, I'm sending `{{child}}` as context to other components. I should not set that context if `selectedstudent` empty?

Comment: Well what do you want to render when no student is selected? (Because there were no students to select from, or when the student is still loading, etc)